# Including Javascript Files (not module) in Kotlin

Tags: javascript, gradle, kotlin

I have two Javascript files. I have some Kotlin code that generates a Javascript file.  I also have a file (call it file.js) that depends on the generated javascript file from Kotlin.

Is there a way for me to include file.js in the Kotlin generated Javascript file using Gradle?  Is there a setting that can append resource Javascript files into the generated output?

My motivation is to slowly transition my Javascript project into Kotlin, and due to the structure of the project, I cannot create a module.  Just want to know if it is possible to do this and how.

Comment: I think its less difficult to merge the whole project in one step

Comment: The project is large and there are a lot of javascript files.  So I know in my question is if you can include 1 file but I will most likely be including a lot more.  I just want to know if it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Gradle's Ant integration for that. Here's an example from [Gradle forums](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/concatenate-more-than-100-files/12014/4):

```
task concat(type: SourceTask) {
    source 'src'
    include '**/*.txt'
    outputs.file new File(buildDir, "full.txt")

    doLast {
        ant.concat(destfile: outputs.files.singleFile) {
            source.addToAntBuilder(ant, 'fileset', FileCollection.AntType.FileSet)
        }
    }
}
```

This will concatenate a bunch of files into a single `full.txt` file - adapt it to your specific case and have the task execute prior to assembling your final build artifact.

I have to say that for Javascript builds Gradle's integration with tools like Gulp and Grunt (via plugins) may be an even better match for you - those tools can naturally handle simple JS file concatenation, but they also offer many more tasks useful for working with web technologies.